# How do I get whitespace to show in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, whitespace

VSCode 1.30.2

I could swear I had this working in previous versions. But now selecting View>Toggle Render Whitespace does not show invisibles such as spaces, tabs, and returns.

My setting for Editor: Render Whitespace is 'all'.

What setting have I missed, or misconfigured? I've run out of places to look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They can be a quite faint gray against certain editor backgrounds.  Try:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {

  "editorWhitespace.foreground": "#ff0000"
}
```

to make sure you really don't have them.